# How to build an array of intervals out of other intervals

Tags: ruby, algorithm, data-structures

Given the following array of intervals:

```
today = Time.current.beginning_of_day
tomorrow = Time.current.tomorrow.beginning_of_day

availabilities = {
  monday: [
    { start_time: today + 6.hours,
      end_of_time: today + 12.hours },
    { start_time: today + 8.hours,
      end_of_time: today + 18.hours }
  ],
  tuesday: [
    { start_time: tomorrow + 10.hours,
      end_time: tomorrow + 16.hours },
    { start_time: tomorrow + 18.hours,
      end_time: tomorrow + 23.hours }
  ]
}
```

How can I build an array of `availabilities` with the intervals in such way that, for instance in the case of `monday` and `tuesday` the hash:

```
# monday
{ start_time: 'Today at 06:00',
  end_time: 'Today at 18:00' }
# tuesday
[ { start_time: 'Tomorrow at 10:00',
    end_time: 'Tomorrow at 16:00' },
  { start_time: 'Tomorrow at 18:00',
    end_time: 'Tomorrow at 23:00' } ]
```

What I want to achieve is to get the intervals of availability for a given day regardless of which entity will provide that availability.

Thanks in advance, any help or guidance on which algorithm to use will much be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithm to merge overlapping intervals :

```
1. Sort the intervals on start time
2. Assign left and right of first interval (0)
3. Iterate over the intervals from 1 to size-1
    if (current interval start lies in prev. interval)
        update right to max(prev. right, current. right) 
    else
        [left, right] is non-overlapping interval => push it to answer array
        reassign left and right to current interval
4. push last [left, right] to answer array
```

Solution:

```
# hash of overlapping intervals
availabilities = {
  monday: [
    { start_time: 6,
      end_time: 12 },
    { start_time: 8,
      end_time: 18 }
  ],
  tuesday: [
    { start_time: 10,
      end_time: 16 },
    { start_time: 18,
      end_time: 23 }
  ]
}

# function for converting hash to intervals, process, and then convert back to hash
def solve(list)
    return_hash = {}
    list.each do |key, arr|
        intervals = []
        arr.each { |hash| intervals << [hash[:start_time], hash[:end_time]] }
        non_overlapping_intervals = merge_interval(intervals)
        temp = []
        non_overlapping_intervals.each { |interval| temp << {start_time: interval[0], end_time: interval[1]} }
        return_hash[key] = temp
    end
    return_hash
end

# algorithm to merge intervals and return non-overlapping intervals
def merge_interval(v)
    intervals = []
    v.sort()
    size = v.size()
    l, r = v[0][0], v[0][1]
    (1...size).each do |i|
        if v[i][0] <= r
            r = [r,v[i][1]].max;
        else
            intervals << [l, r]
            l, r = v[i][0], v[i][1]
        end         
    end
    intervals << [l, r]
    return intervals
end

# solve call for availabilities hash
p solve(availabilities)
```

Output:

```
{
 :monday=>[{:start_time=>6, :end_time=>18}],
 :tuesday=>[{:start_time=>10, :end_time=>16},
            {:start_time=>18, :end_time=>23}]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Sort the intervals by start time
2. Start with the first interval and check if it overlaps the next.
3. If yes, then merge them and repeat the process
4. If no, proceed to the next interval.

Proof that it works:

If interval A, B, and C are sorted, and A and C overlap, it also means that B overlaps with A for sure.

Here's one way to implement this in Ruby.

```
def overlap?(r1, r2)
  !(r1.end <= r2.begin || r1.begin >= r2.end)
end

def merge_intervals(r1, r2)
  [r1.begin, r2.begin].min..[r1.end, r2.end].max
end

def flatten_intervals(intervals)
  first, *rest = intervals.sort_by(&:begin)
  rest.each_with_object([first]) { |r,stack| stack <<
    (overlap?(stack.last, r) ? merge_intervals(stack.pop, r) : r) }
end

intervals = [0..2, 5..8, 4..9, 11..13, 15..17, 19..21, 17..19, 16..20]
flatten_intervals(intervals)
  #=> [0..2, 4..9, 11..13, 15..21]
```

Comment: Excellent algorithm: efficient and easily understood! Code would have been good, but I consider that omission minor.

Comment: ElKamina, please feel free to edit or delete the code I added. It is such a nice answer I thought some code would round it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way to convert an array of time intervals to an array of non-overlapping time intervals. I've assumed the granularity is one hour (but changing that to minutes or seconds is straightforward). For convenience I've also represented time intervals as ranges rather than the hashes specified in the question (though it would be easy to convert the ranges to hashes).

Suppose

```
time_intervals = [0..2, 5..8, 4..9, 11..13, 15..17, 19..21, 17..19, 16..20]
```

We can view these intervals as follows:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
xx xx xx       xx xx xx xx       xx xx xx    xx xx xx    xx xx xx
            xx xx xx xx xx xx                      xx xx xx 
                                                xx xx xx xx xx
```

We wish to combine these thusly:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
xx xx xx    xx xx xx xx xx xx    xx xx xx    xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx
```

An easy way is as follows.

```
h = 24.times.with_object({}) { |i,h| h[i] = :uncovered } 
time_intervals.each { |range|
  (range.begin..range.end).each { |i| h[i] = :covered } }
h.delete_if { |_,v| v == :uncovered }.
  keys.
  slice_when { |k1, k2| k2 - k1 > 1 }.
  map { |a| a.first..a.last }
  #=> [0..2, 4..9, 11..13, 15..21]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
h = 24.times.with_object({}) { |i,h| h[i] = :uncovered } 
  #=> {0=>:uncovered, 1=>:uncovered, 2=>:uncovered,..., 23=>:uncovered} 
time_intervals.each { |range|
  (range.begin..range.end).each { |i| h[i] = :covered } }
h #=> { all k=>:covered except k=>:uncovered for k = 3, 10, 14, 22 and 23 } 
g = h.delete_if { |_,v| v == :uncovered }
  #=> { all k=>:covered, k = 1,2, 4,5,6,7,8,9, 11,12,13, 15,16,17,18,19,20,21v]
k = g.keys
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21] 
e = k.slice_when { |k1, k2| k2 - k1 > 1 }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fee0a05c7b0>:each>
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator as follows:

```
e.entries
  #=> [[0, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [11, 12, 13], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]]
```

See [Enumerable#entries](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-entries). [Enumerable#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a) can also be used.

The final step is to convert the arrays to ranges.

```
e.map { |a| a.first..a.last }
  #=> [0..2, 4..9, 11..13, 15..21]
```

Comment: `time_intervals = [0..2, 3..4]` will ignore the pause between 2 and 3.

Comment: @Eric, that was the intent, as I treat `0..2` and `3..4` as collections of hours (`[0,1,2]` and `[3,4]`) rather than representations of continuous intervals.I'm not especially fond of this solution, however.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't answer the question, then.

Answer (score 0):

With a slightly different format (a Range instead of a Hash with inconsistent keys), this problem becomes easier :

```
today = 0
tomorrow = 24

availabilities = {
  monday: [
    { start_time: today + 6,
      end_time: today + 12 },
    { start_time: today + 8,
      end_time: today + 18 }
  ],
  tuesday: [
    { start_time: tomorrow + 10,
      end_time: tomorrow + 16 },
    { start_time: tomorrow + 18,
      end_time: tomorrow + 23 }
  ]
}

availabilities = availabilities.map do |day, avails|
  [ day,
    avails.map do |avail|
      (avail[:start_time]..avail[:end_time])
    end
  ]
end.to_h
# {:monday=>[6..12, 8..18], :tuesday=>[34..40, 42..47]}
```

You can then use the [range-operator gem](https://github.com/monocle/range_operators) to sum ranges.